# Ocultar/Exibir campos texto na view

Tags: c#, asp.net

Tenho uma tabela com campos dropdownlist e editorfor para preenchimento da requisição do usuário. Preciso acrescentar agora uma nova funcionalidade que é: Se o usuário selecionar uma opção específica no dropdowlist 'Unidade' dois novos campos devem aparecer na tabela (Numero e Motivo) Caso não seja essa a opção selecionada, a tabela fica como está, ou seja, como ela abre para o usuário. Como posso fazer isso? Consigo fazer só alterando a view ou preciso alterar algo no controle também?

```
 <div class="title">
    Selecione a Unidade:</div>
<div>@Html.DropDownList("Unidade", string.Empty)
    <button type="submit">
        Ok</button>  // Após clique nesse ok com a tal unidade selecionada ou simplesmente selecionando a determinada opção, os campos 'Numero' e 'Motivo' devem aparecer para preenchimento obrigatório.
</div>
<table>
    <tr>
        <th> Nome </th>
        <th> Data </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>@Html.DropDownList("Nome", string.Empty)
        </td>
        <td>@Html.EditorFor(x => x.Date)
        </td>
        <td>@Html.EditorFor(x => x.Numero) // Deve ficar oculto a menos q tal opção..
        </td>
        <td>@Html.EditorFor(x => x.Motivo) // Deve ficar oculto a menos q tal opção seja selecionada
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<div class="formfooter">
    <button type="submit">
        Salvar</button></div>
</div>


    public ActionResult AddItems(RequestItem item)
    {
        SetTempData();
        item.Solicitacao_Id = requestId;

        if (_data.RequestItems.IsValid(item))
        {
            _data.RequestItems.Insert(item);

            _data.Save();
            return RedirectToAction("ViewItems");
        }

        InitializeData(null, null, null, item.Unidade_Id);
        return View(item);

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Acredito que precise alterar somente na View mesmo, escondendo os campos quando o usuário selecionar alguma opção para o DDL de Unidade

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

   //Escondendo campos quando carregar página
   $('#Numero, #Motivo').hide();

   // Exibindo/ Escondendo conforme valor de Unidade
   $('#Unidade').change(function(){
        if (this.value == [valor para habilitar Numero e Motivo]){
            $('#Numero, #Motivo').show();
        }else{
            $('#Numero, #Motivo').show();
        }
   });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Eu preciso acrescentar algo mais na minha view ou aplicação para ela ler esse código Javascript @Jkzari ? Pq só eu colocando esse código na view não altera em nada. Já entra na aplicação mostrando os campos que deveriam estar ocultos...

Comment: Vitor, vc precisa da biblioteca jquery. Baixe-a no seu projeto por NuGet (se já não estiver disponível).

Esta linha é a que esconde os DDLs: 

 //Escondendo campos quando carregar página
   $('#Numero, #Motivo').hide();
   
altere para 
 $('#[ID do dropdownlist numero], #[ID do dropdownlist motivo]').hide();
   
para saber o id do campo clique com o direito em cima dele e clique em inspecionar elemento

Comment: Ok, instalei a biblioteca pelo NuGet, mas mesmo assim o script continua não dando resultado. O id está certo, conferi ao inspecionar o elemento. Tá certinho. O que mais pode ser?

Comment: Ótimo! Deu certo agora! Obrigado

Comment: esse meu dropdownlist que faço a seleção da unidade, possui um botão ok associado a ele. Através da seleção dele, outro campo que não coloquei na view chamado situação também é carregado via dropdownlist com as situações correspondentes a unidade selecionada. O javascript está funcionando legal quando eu seleciono a devido unidade. porém ao clicar no ok que é necessário para carregar o outro dropdownlist, os campos somem. Como posso carrega-los também através do ok?

Comment: Vc precisa de um dropdownlist que venha de um ajax/json? certo? Eu não sei exatamente como fazer, tenho que fazer algo parecido no meu trabalho. Pesquisa sobre 'dropdownlist com ajax mvc' (https://www.google.com.br/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#safe=off&q=dropdownlist+com+ajax+mvc) ,  depois eu posto como eu fiz pra você.

Comment: Ok! Se conseguir posto aqui também!

Comment: @Jkzari quando você precisa adicionar outras informações a sua resposta você, edita ela e adiciona nela mesma ao invés de postar uma nova resposta. Aqui não é um fórum. Uma única resposta deve conter todas as informações necessárias para a solução do problema. Os comentários sim podem ser usados para discutir a solução e chegar na melhor resposta possível, como você fizeram.

Comment: ok @bigown farei assim daqui pra frente, obrigado pela ajuda.

Comment: @PFVictor já fez o dropdownlist? eu tenho um código funcionando aqui...

Comment: @Jkzari fiz um dropdowlist mas peguei o projeto novamente para fazer outra alteração e tive o mesmo problema. Acrescentei a validacao mas quando eu clico em salvar os campos somem e a mensagem de erro não aparece, mas continua na mesma tela. Quando eu desmarco o checkbox os campos deviam sumir também, mas eles continuam lá. Como corrigir esses pequenos detalhes?

Comment: Vitor posta o código com as alterações em uma nova questão, abç

Answer (score 1):

Vitor, adiciona esta linha que deve funcionar:

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
```

Segue o código que eu usei pra testar:

```
<div class="title">
    Selecione a Unidade:

    <select id="Unidade">
        <option>1</option>
        <option>2</option>
        <option>3</option>
        <option>4</option>
    </select>
</div>

<p class="ocultar"> Número: @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Numero) // Deve ficar oculto a menos q tal opção.. </p>
<p class="ocultar"> Motivo: @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Motivo) // Deve ficar oculto a menos q tal opção seja selecionada </p>

<br/>

<button type="submit">
        Salvar
</button>

@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")

<script language="Javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

        //Escondendo campos quando carregar página
        $('.ocultar').hide();

        // Exibindo/ Escondendo conforme valor de Unidade
        $('#Unidade').change(function () {
            if (this.value == 1) {
                $('.ocultar').hide();
                $('#Numero, #Motivo').val('');
            } else {
                $('.ocultar').show();
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```